# ReadDirectoryChangesW как понять, что был удален файл или папка

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте, использую функцию `ReadDirectoryChangesW` для мониторинга изменений в каталоге. Можно ли, при удалении какого-либо компонента(папка/файл), распознать, что он является именно папкой или файлом?

Answer (score 1):

Да можно. Эта функция должна записывать изменения в переданный вами буфер, состоящий из структур [FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364391(v=vs.85).aspx). Собственно в этих структурах записано, кроме того что произошло с элементом, еще и имя элемента. Зная имя элемента вы можете получить его атрибуты с помощью функции [GetFileAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364944(v=vs.85).aspx). Атрибуты здесь это просто `DWORD`, то есть набор флажков. Так вот, один из этих флажков, а именно `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`, указывает на то, что элемент является папкой.

Чтобы обрабатывать случаи удаления элементов с учетом их типа (файл или папка), нужно дополнительно хранить и обновлять атрибуты всех элементов. То есть после каждого вызова `ReadDirectoryChanges` потребуется обновлять атрибуты измененных элементов. Ну и если элемент удален, то его тип вы узнаете из предыдущего списка атрибутов в котором он еще был.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как это работает. Если я знаю имя элемента, как я могу получить атрибуты? Ведь, на момент проверки атрибутов, этого файла уже не будет существовать.

Comment: @kast96 дополнил ответ